# move cursor in insert mode from line2 head to line1 tail in vim

Tags: vim

```
1234
5678
```

In insert mode,if I want to move cursor from 5 to 4
please tell me what should I do? 
I dont want to change to normal mode and press `k$`
Is there some way to do it in Insert mode?
Something like using `<-` key to move it.

If I want to use `<-` to do this ,what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The usual Vim way would be indeed to switch back to normal mode. You can then do
`kA`, `bA`, for example. If you want  your arrow keys to work across lines, have
a look in the `whichwrap` option, [`:h whichwrap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'ww'). For the arrows to work in
insert mode, try use this (you can add in *.vimrc*):

```
set whichwrap+=[,]
```

It is usual to make the arrows work in normal and visual too:

```
set ww+=<,>,[,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to remember is that <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> puts you in normal mode for one command only. So <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> <kbd>$</kbd> would put you at the tail of the previous line, still in insert mode.

Comment: Well remembered! Although I find it a bit too complicated. Maybe `ge` can be useful because it counts as one control-o only but still would need a right movement because of the cursor position. Another alternative is to move up and use the end key, if you have one in your keyboard, or a combination form the system which does that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key with the <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow right</kbd><kbd>Arrow up</kbd>

Comment: This works as long as the given lines are at the end of the buffer, since `i_<C-Right>` is like `w` command in normal mode. See [`:help i_<C-Right>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_%3CC-Right%3E) for more information.